# How to rewrite certain URLs in webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am creating a React & react-router v4 application bundled with Webpack. I am creating [async split points](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/) with Webpack to async load bundles for react-router routes of my application on-demand.

Assuming my app is called "myapp", when I deploy this to my server my static assets need to be served from:

```
/myapp/static/<assetName>
```

In order for the async bundle loading to work when deploying to the server, my Webpack output config is as follows:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  publicPath: "/myapp/static/",
  chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js",
  filename: "[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js"
}
```

In my devServer section I have this:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  inline: true,
  port: 4000,
  publicPath: "/myapp" // this is so my app is served from http://locahost:4000/myapp 
}
```

I don't have any issues when I actually deploy to my server, however when I run webpack-dev-server and I access:

```
http://localhost:4000/myapp
```

...the html is served up, but all the URLs generated for my bundles by `HtmlWebpackPlugin` are `/myapp/static/<bundleName>` and therefore fail to fetch as the bundles are being served at `/mpapp/<bundleName>`.

How can I configure webpack-dev-server to rewrite `/myapp/static/<bundleName>` to `/myapp/<bundleName>` so that it will route to the bundles that are actually being served locally under `/myapp`?

I've tried all manner of rewrite and proxy directives, but I just seem to break the app - I'm sure there's a simple way that I'm overlooking.

Many thanks.

Comment: Another possible option here is I change my build process. So for local dev my webpack config just serves bundles normally and then my prod build process uses the specific /myapp/static publicPath directive?

Comment: I have written a basic node.js express server using webpack-dev-middleware that achieves what I want - basically I map a static path to my public path: `app.use("/myapp/static", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public")));`. Is there a way I can achieve this with webpack-dev-server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the index for `historyApiFallback` like this:

```
historyApiFallback: {
  index: "/myapp/static/"
},
```

For more information, refer to the `webpack` and `connect-history-api-fallback` docs:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback
https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback